# Angular ng-click not working with data-toggle="toggle"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, toggle

I am trying to use `data-toggle="toggle"` (from: http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/ ) on a checkbox. However, this breaks angulars ng-click and ng-change... They are simply not firing the function. Does anyone have a solution for this? 
Code snippet below:

```
<input type="checkbox"  
       ng-click="testFunction()" 
       ng-model="testValue" 
       checked 
       data-toggle="toggle">
```

Comment: You don't seem to have an `ng-change` in the code. Also have you tried wrapping the `testFunction()` in double quotes? Either way a Plunkr would be useful

Comment: i tried with both ng-change or ng-click, both dont work.

Comment: Ok The reason it doesn't work is that Bootstrap Toggle  is not made to work with Angular. Changing the DOM in any way that isn't through Angular, eg through jQuery like Toggle does, will cause conflicts with Angular's control of the DOM, and indeed it will not register DOM changes that don't happen through Angular.

Comment: If that answer helped I will post it as an answer and please accept it :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason it doesn't work is that Bootstrap Toggle is not made to work with Angular. Changing the DOM in any way that isn't through Angular, eg through jQuery like Toggle does, will cause conflicts with Angular's control of the DOM, and indeed it will not register DOM changes that don't happen through Angular.